# how to query for unpaired values of a property

Tags: sql

I have a table with TransactionIDs and TransactionTypes. I have 2 types of transactions (deposits and cash outs) and each transaction has a transaction ID. I need to retrieve the transaction IDs that are attributed only to deposits and not to cash outs.

This is the Transactions table:

```
TransactionType    TransactionID
--------------------------------
Deposit                 1234         
Cashout                 1234       
Cashout                 12345          
Cashout                 123456        
Deposit                 1256      
Deposit                 12345
Deposit                 123456
Deposit                 777
```

This is the result I need:

```
TransactionType    TransactionID
--------------------------------
Deposit                 1256      
Deposit                 777
```

Can anyone help me with a sql query that gives me the needed result?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, provide sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the help of subquery:

```
select transactionId from <table> where transactiontType = 'Deposit' 
and transactionId not in 
(select transactionId from <table> where transactiontType = 'Cashout');
```

In this way you can filter out transaction ids with cash out as transaction type

Answer (score 2):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE transactiontType = 'Deposit' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t1 WHERE t1.transactionid = t.transactionid AND t1.transactiontType <> t.transactiontType);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXCEPT` to return the transactionId's with deposit, except those with Cashout:

```
select transactionId from tablename where transactiontType = 'Deposit' 
except
select transactionId from tablename where transactiontType = 'Cashout'
```